# Where put server,client files in apache thrift

Tags: apache, thrift

I'm new to the apache thrift. I've successfully installed apache thrift to the machine. Then I wrote a thrift file.

```
typedef i64 long
typedef i32 int
service ArithmeticService { 
            long add(1:int num1, 2:int num2),
}
```

Then I used `thrift --gen java file_name.thrift` to generate Service file. It was created under `gen-java` directory. Then I have no idea where(the directory) I put my server, client java files. I tried in various places but that files cannot resolved thrift in-build things like `TExcepetion` , etc. So how can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You structure your project exactly as you would do with any other Java project. Just make sure the generated files and the Thrift library are included into your project. A very recommended place to start is the [Apache Thrift Java tutorial](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/java/), which also includes an `ant` file.